# Counting the unique number of times a certain book exists in different libraries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have  SQL table that has the following structure. I know this might be not the best way to represent the data, but this is how I obtained the data.

```
BOOKID  LibraryID

2m4           1          
2m4           1
3ds           3
3ds           1
3ds           2
5tR           1
2m4           4
```

I want to make a query to find for a certain book how many library does it exist in. I am not interested in the copies. I just want to know the number of different libraries a book is in regardless of the copies in a certain library.

So in the example above if I want to count the number of libraries the book with ID 2m4 the answer should be only 2 as it only exists in two libraries regardless of how many copies each library holds.

I tried:

```
select bookid,count(*) from books group by bookid
```

It gave me the number of times the book appeared in the table even if it is repeated in the same library. What I am looking for is counting unique times the book exist in different libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Op if you are asking a general question for say ANSI Standard SQL, please only use the `sql` tag, or please pick a product, different version / products can have different answers.

Comment: @Random_User I fixed it. Thank you for your note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT keyword and specify LibraryID:

```
    select bookid,count(distinct LibraryID) from books group by bookid
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. That is what I needed.